# How to remove underline from current composing text in Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard-events

Is there a way to remove the underline from the text currently being typed in an `EditText`?

I **need** to keep the suggestions area as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

XML:

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Code:
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

Comment: I need suggestions, but I don't want the underline.

Comment: EditText.clearComposingText() removes the underline (but it doesn't disable).